# How would I make a mute script without getting errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, discord

Ignore the weird title, it wouldn't let me type anything good.

so I've made a mute command which unmutes you after a certain amount of time, I'm not sure why it won't work. Please help, Thanks so much!

```js
bot.on('message', message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");


    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'mute':
            **Let person = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[1]))**
            if (!person) return message.reply("That user isn't in this server");

            **Let mainrole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "›› Member");
            Let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Muted");**

            if (!muterole) return message.reply("Couldn't find the mute role.");

            **Let time = args[2];**

            if (!time) {
                return message.reply("You didn't specify a time!")
            }

            person.roles.remove(mainrole.id);
            person.roles.add(mainrole.id);

            message.channel.send(`@${person.user.tag} has now been muted for ${ms(ms(time))}`);

            setTimeout(function () {
                person.addRole(mainrole.id);
                person.removeRole(muterole.id);
                message.channel.send(`@${person.tag} has now been unmuted.`)
            }, ms(time));


            break;
    }


});



bot.login(token);
```

Comment: *I'm not sure why it won't work*, have you checked for any errors in the console? At first glance I see `**` which isn't valid JavaScript. Are you trying to make a comment? Also the keyword `let` in capital letters will break it for sure.

Comment: No I'm trying to say that that's where the errors are.

Comment: Oh it was because ( let ) was capital, thanks so much!